# How do you retrieve the name of the publication that is the source of the retrieved news article?

Tags: ibm-watson, alchemyapi

The [Alchemy News API](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wN0e_fhYCO7GBAneN9xjrNo57OtS_0Tr8FI9xCMfmzM/edit#gid=0) has many fields that can be retrieved when fetching news articles.  However, the name of the publication that originally published the article does not seem to be one of them.  This seems like an unlikely omission.  Am I just not seeing it?

Answer (score 0):

We don't have that field in the API.